# Remove Title suffix from cms pages

Tags: magento-1.7, seo, page-title, cms-pages

I have title suffix in magento 1.7 system configuration.

I would like to remove title suffix from all cms pages or from cms pages besides home page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

IN file:

```
  app/design/frontend/{theme}/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

search:

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

In place of it put below code and test:

```
<?php if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() =='cms' && Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()!='home') { ?>
      <?php 
      $prefix = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
      $title = $this->getTitle();
      $processedTitle = trim(substr($title, 0, strpos($title, $prefix)));
      ?>
      <title><?php echo $processedTitle; ?></title>
 <?php } else {?>
      <title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
 <?php }?>
```

Comment: Thanx! Great work!

Comment: @samdecks if it works for you, you can accept the answer by clicking on above button.

Comment: @samdecks if above code works for you, you can accept the answer.